# Laravel 4 regex:pattern validation for password not working

Tags: regex, validation, laravel-4

I'm trying to check my password strength in Laravel 4 using regex:pattern validation. I'm trying it in following way but it is always giving me 'Password is weak' in return if my $validator validation passes.

```
public function checkPassStrength(){
    $password = Input::get('password');
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'password' => 'alpha_dash|min:6'
    ));
    $niceNames = array(
        'password' => 'Password'
    );
    $validator->setAttributeNames($niceNames);
    if($validator->fails()) {
        return Response::json(array('valid' => false, 'msg' => $validator->messages()->first('password')));
    } else {
        $strong = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
            'password' => array('regex:/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])$/')
        ));
        $medium = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
            'password' => array('regex:/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])$/')
        ));
        if($strong->passes()){
            return Response::json(array('valid' => false, 'msg' => 'Password is strong'));
        } elseif($medium->passes()){
            return Response::json(array('valid' => false, 'msg' => 'Password is medium'));
        } else {
            return Response::json(array('valid' => false, 'msg' => 'Password is weak'));
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookahead is a zerolength assertion, add `.+` at the end of the regex:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).+$/
```

Or, if you want to limit the length from 8 to 20 characters:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,20}$/
```

Comment: The first solution worked perfectly, as for limiting the length I already have validated it earlier. Thanks a lot